# MySQL LEFT JOIN 2 columns

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM timetable 
LEFT JOIN user 
ON timetable.id = user.id
WHERE timetable.id = 1
//this only display 1 column's name from user table
//id  partner name  time
//1   2       Ben   2015-05-17

//user
id  name
1   Ben
2   Lisa

//timetable
id  partner  time
1   2        123456484

//What I need is display like this
Ben  Lisa    2015-05-17
```

I have a 2 tables user and timetable

user table store id and name

timetable store id which partner group together

Now, I need to join these 2 tables together and display their name

I try to join but it only shows one column's name

anyone know how to display 2 columns?

Comment: Please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Always specify the columns you actually want returned in your SELECT clause. If two columns from two separate tables have the same name, prefix each, so SQL knows which table(s) to look at, and alias them, so you (and any subsequent parser) know which is which. E.g. `SELECT a.x, a.y AS a_y, b.y AS b_y FROM a JOIN b ON b.id  = a.id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your explanation is not clear. But here is my guess:

```
SELECT 
  u.name,
  p.name,
  t.time 
FROM timetable t
LEFT JOIN user u
ON timetable.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN user p
ON timetable.partner = p.id
WHERE timetable.id = 1
```